# Finding the name of a window

Tags: xorg, xmonad

I tried to find the name of the xev window, so that I can make xmonad
float it, but xprop returned

```
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        program specified size: 178 by 178
        program specified minimum size: 78 by 78
WM_COMMAND(STRING) = { "xev" }
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Event Tester"
```

and neither "Event Tester" nor "xev" seems to be the right name.  At
least inserting it here

```
myManageHook = composeAll
[ className =? "MPlayer"            --> doFloat
, className =? "Gimp"               --> doFloat
, className =? "Udiskie"            --> doFloat
, className =? "XClock"             --> doFloat
, className =? "Xmessage"           --> doFloat
, className =? "Event Tester"           --> doFloat
]
```

did not have the expected effect.  How do I find the name?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
appName =? "Event Tester"           --> doFloat
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the window manager name, use `title` instead of `className`. In your case, what you are looking for is this.

```
myManageHook = composeAll
[ className =? "MPlayer"            --> doFloat
, className =? "Gimp"               --> doFloat
, className =? "Udiskie"            --> doFloat
, className =? "XClock"             --> doFloat
, className =? "Xmessage"           --> doFloat
, title     =? "Event Tester"       --> doFloat
]
```